# What does this colon do in struct? it is not a bitfield

Tags: c++, struct

In C programming, What does this colon do in struct?

```
struct ABC:XYZ {int num;}
```

where XYZ is also a struct. This does not seem to be a bitfield. What does ':' mean here?

Comment: Inheritance. ABC inherits from XYZ

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++-only questions. That is no valid C construct, but C++ class inheritance.

Comment: @Olaf: The OP obviously thought that this was a C question. The first line even says, "In C programming, [...]". So the real problem is the accidentally-correctly tagging it with C++.

Comment: Ok, so he confuses C++ with C. Ok, it'll take back the harsh sound off my comment, but leave the rest as a friendly hint. (OTOH: if he thought that was C, why adding C++ tags?)

Comment: thanks everyone! right, I thought it was C. And even in C++, I did not know struct can inherit from another struct. It's good to know.

Comment: @user2014033: It's because in C++, there isn't really such a thing as a struct; `struct` is just a synonym for `class`, except with an implicit `public:` instead of an implicit `private:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
struct ABC:XYZ {int num;}
```

means "define a struct `ABC` which inherits from `XYZ` and has a `num` member of type `int`. Specifically the `:` means "inherits from".

That code is equivalent to:

```
struct ABC : public XYZ {int num;}
```

For `struct`s the default inheritance visibility is `public`, for `class`es it's `private`.

Answer (score 2):

When inherit you usually write:

```
class Child : public Parent { ... };
```

you can also write

```
class Child : Parent { ... };
```

but for class that would be private inheritance, so you usually see keyword `public` there. Same for `struct` except if not specified explicitly it would be already `public`.